# Import Modules in PyQt5

Tags: python, import, module, pyqt5

I'm with some problems for adding widgets with PyQt5 to one QMainWindow working with different modules. Basically my GUI has many windows and widgets and i think that would be more organized working with different modules. However, when i try to add a widget from one module to the main module, it gives me an error like the class i'm trying to import is not defined.

To simplify, below you have a very simple test i tried and got the same error of my GUI script. I have two modules, one i called "main_gui_file" and the other is "widget_file".

main_gui_file in this example is the QMainWindow i load in the screen, and i'd like to add a widget in my self.grid_01 calling a function in the module widget_file.

When i run this test, it gives me NameError: name 'Add_Widgets' is not defined

Below you have the both test modules

main_gui_file

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys

from teste.widget_file import *

class Main_GUI(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(Main_GUI, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 500, 500)

        self.main_widget = QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)

        self.widget_01 = QWidget()
        self.main_widget.addWidget(self.widget_01)
        self.grid_01 = QGridLayout()
        self.widget_01.setLayout(self.grid_01)
        self.main_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.widget_01)

        self.label1 = QLabel('a')
        self.label2 = QLabel('b')
        self.grid_01.addWidget(self.label1, 0, 0)
        self.grid_01.addWidget(self.label2, 1, 0)

        self.add_widgets = Add_Widgets()
        self.add_widgets.add_widget()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Main_GUI()

window.show()
app.exec_()
```

widget_file

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

from teste.main_gui_file import *

class Add_Widgets(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(Add_Widgets, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.main_gui = Main_GUI()

    def add_widget(self):

        self.label3 = QLabel('c')
        self.main_gui.grid_01.addWidget(self.label3, 3, 0)
```

Does anyone know why i'm facing this trouble to import the module?
Thanks

Comment: Just to complete my question... Both files are in the same folder

Comment: Do you realize you're doing a circular import?

Comment: I tried to import only from the main widget, in the same example and using a parameter in the widget function, but it didn't worked as well

Comment: I edited my question and changed the ciclic import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important problem in your code is that you're doing a circular import (which is usually *bad*).

In generic terms, this means that until something "happens", it will not go further with the code.

That's (almost) what is happening:

- `main_gui_file` is loaded and at a certain point it tries to import from `widget_file`
- `widget_file` is being imported and tries to load from `main_gui_file`
- `main_gui_file` is processed again, but it *tries* to go along with it (*simple* circular imports are not a real issue, as Python *could* be able manage them), but at this point `widget_file` is *not* going to be completely imported until the `main_gui_file` has completed
- the imported `main_gui_file` *from* `widget_file` is now trying to complete the loading
- the imported `main_gui_file` also tries to create an instance of `Main_GUI`, which in turns requires `Add_Widgets`, which exists in `widget_file`, but, at that point, it has not been loaded yet, since the import processing is still occupied by trying to complete the loading of `main_gui_file`
- Python yells at you because no `Add_Widgets` exists yet

But that's not enough.

There's a logical problem even on top of that (as [@NaufanRusydaFaikar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8791891) partially explains): you're trying to create a **new** instance of `Main_GUI` in the `Add_Widgets` class, which doesn't make a lot of sense, since one already exists, and *that* instance is the one you're going to add the widget to.

Also, for the same reason, if you want to add widgets to an existing instance, you really shouldn't create a new QMainWindow, since you're not actually going to use it.

From your code I don't really understand why you need another file to do all that (you *might* have a good reason, but your code shows none), but I'm going along with it suggesting the following modifications:

main_gui_file.py:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
import sys

from widget_file import *

class Main_GUI(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...
        add_widget(self, self.grid_01)
```

widget_file.py:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

def add_widget(parent, layout): # <-- note that there's no "self"
    parent.label3 = QLabel('c')
    layout.addWidget(parent.label3, 3, 0)
```

As you can see, `add_widget` is now an "orphan" function (by "orphan" I mean that it has no relation besides the module it belongs to, and that can be seen from the fact that it has no indentation **and** that the first argument is not a `self` argument it can be related to).
Technically, you could even do the same just by calling `add_widget` with the layout argument alone and using `def add_widget(layout):`, but that would prevent you to set the `label3` object as an attribute of the main window.

An alternate and better solution (which would also solve the previous logical issue) would be the following:

main_gui_file.py

```
# ...
class Main_GUI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...
        self.label3 = add_widget(self.grid_01)
```

But only as long as you return the added widget in `widget_file.py`:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

def add_widget(layout):
    label = QLabel('c')
    layout.addWidget(label, 3, 0)
    return label
```

Note that this is not a very *elegant* way of doing things, as separate imports like these are usually done for "common" functions ("util" functions you usually call for common tasks that don't need an instance argument), and, when dealing with these kind of objects, it's something usually done whenever the imported objects are classes for which instances are going to be created, but that's really a completely different issue.

Comment: thanks for the explanation... now it's clearly to me

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have file `__init__.py` in your module directory. Second, from your example, you've tried to import both files which are placed in the same directory. So, try to import the relative path, `from teste.widget_file import *` would be `from .widget_file import *` and `from teste.main_gui_file import *` would be `from .main_gui_file import *`.

---

Edit:

To avoid cyclic import, I suggest to change your code to

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject

class Add_Widgets(QObject):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Add_Widgets, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.main_gui = parent

    ...
```

So you can create Add_Widgets instance by

```
class Main_GUI(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(Main_GUI, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        ...

        self.add_widgets = Add_Widgets(self)
```

Comment: the __init__ functions are in both modules... i changed to relative paths but i got the error ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: I guess it's because of cyclic import

Comment: @NaufanRusydaFaikar That has nothing to do with the `__init__.py`, but with the fact that a `QApplication.exec()` is blocking, which prevents the circular import to complete.

Comment: I edited my question and changed the ciclic import, but still not working NameError: name 'Main_GUI' is not defined

Comment: Please, don't edit your question if it doesn't solve your problem, especially if the editing removes the main issue about your code and introduces other and different issues.

Comment: @R.Leal please undo the latest change you made to your post.

Comment: @NaufanRusydaFaikar I stand corrected, sorry: the problem is not even about the blocking application, but the instance creation.

Comment: @NaufanRusydaFaikar by parent you mean the main class? Main_GUI ... to do this i still need to import the modules in both files

Comment: No, by doing that, you don't have to `from teste.main_gui_file import *` anymore. Is it not working?

Comment: @NaufanRusydaFaikar NameError: name 'parent' is not defined